# Modules over $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ have $p$-power order

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> I am given that $M$ is a module over $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$, where $p$ is a prime and $M$ is finite. How can I show that the order of $M$ is $p^j$ for some $j$?

The ring $Z/p^nZ$ is not a PID since it's not an integral domain. Therefore, I am not guaranteed a basis for $M$ over $Z/p^nZ$. If I had a basis of size $k$, then I can conclude that the order of $M$ is $p^{nk}$. Are there any theorems that will furnish a basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of $M$ as a $\mathbf Z$ module and apply the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID.

Comment: @Shubhodip Mondal I have never used this theorem. Am I using it properly if I say $M\cong Z/pZ \oplus \cdots \oplus Z/p^nZ$? If now, what do the prime factors have to do with $M$?

Comment: It tells you that number of elements in $M$ is a power of $p$ right?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I meant "if not". Thanks.